# Marketing Cloud platform upgrade

Tags: marketing-cloud

Just the way Salesforce has 3 core upgrade per year, does Marketing Cloud have upgrades. The only reference I found was [Marketing Cloud Infrastructure Upgrade](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000264636&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1)  but this seems to be a one time upgrade at their end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marketing cloud does have upgrades even i would say they are upgrading it with very short time releases. In 2018 itself there are five releases scheduled. I did not find anywhere which tells about their release strategy for Marketing cloud but i would say it has changed so much within 2 years.

[image]

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_2018_release_schedule.htm&type=5)